# deploy node on azure free tier

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service

We can deploy but the problem is that when the command "npm install" runs, the node_modules take to much space.
This is just a POC so the employer wouldn't spend more to upgrade to payed plan.
We are restricted to 1GB for back and frontend.
Any possible way to reduce the size of the project?

Comment: Create a new Azure account, you'll get $250 free credits for the first month but IMHO, if your employer can't spend $50 on a Cloud POC, it's time to look elsewhere.

Comment: I'm the only medior on the project, I think it is just to keep the ones without a client busy. I just work here for a month. I suggested google cloud, but was out of question, it had to be Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with how we deployed the node application, but the limitations of the free tier. We have deployed it to google cloud with jenkins and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the the installed **npm modules directory size** as well as the **npm cache directory size**.

They are located under `D:\local\AppData` as shown below:

[image]

If the npm cache size is large, you can save some storage space by cleaning the cache using the npm command below:

```
npm cache clean
```

> clean: Delete all data out of the cache folder.

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

In addition, if the node modules size is large, you can also save some storage space by running the command below to remove the npm modules for devDependencies.

```
npm prune --production
```

> If the --production flag is specified or the NODE_ENV environment
>   variable is set to production, this command will remove the packages
>   specified in your devDependencies

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune

Hope this helps.

Comment: we got a message that we exceeded the quota for the free tier.But will try those

Comment: Please try and let me know if my suggestion helps, thanks

Comment: It helped to deploy the application, but further problems came. The process of building and deploying the application takes a certain amount of CPU usage which exceeds the free tier according a more experienced college of mine. Don't know the exact details, a project partner of mine was calling him. So he will suggest to the manager to take a payed plan.

Answer (score 0):

You may install with `npm install --production` to avoid installing your projects' dev dependencies.

Read more in the [`npm install` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

> With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies